# AngularJs Json Ng-repeat with Button Control

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Here is a project I am working on for fun trying to get used to the ng-repeat directive. I created the following so far.

Its working but I am attempting to add more to this to make it work better. I have been trying to add either buttons or a drop down menu to select part of my JSON to do the ng-repeat on.

In my example I have workout days with exercises.

I would like a drop down menu showing the days One thing I have been researching and haven't found much that is doing this.

Basically I want it to load the exercises from the JSON based on the selection of the drop down days menu all coming from my JSON file.

PLUNKER:
http://plnkr.co/edit/IRis4l3r0MVCjpLNd3Q3

```
var app = angular.module('app', []).config(function($sceDelegateProvider) {
$sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
// Allow same origin resource loads.
'self',
'http://*.bodybuilding.com/**'
]);
});
app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope) {


$scope.data = {JSON FILE}

$scope.exercises = [];
angular.forEach($scope.data.day, function(day, index) {
  console.log(day);
  angular.forEach(day.exercises, function(exercise, index){
    //console.log(posters);
    $scope.exercises.push(exercise);
  });
});
console.log($scope.data);

});
```

*Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forked your plunker and the dropdown is now organized by your day array in $scope.data, and inside each dropdown item it is repeated each exercise name.

You could check it here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/DoIBDv2w0vY4zAWSq89D?p=preview

```
//Important html code
<li><a href="#" ng-repeat="day in data.day" ng-click="selectedDay($index)">day {{$index}}  |  <span ng-repeat="exercise in day.exercises">{{exercise.name}}</span></a></li>
```

Try clicking on a dropdown element.

Basically, you need a ng-repeat inside a ng-repeat, since you are iterating first over the days, and for each day you want to interate over it's exercises.

Hope I helped :)

Comment: I see that does help out I am going to keep playing with it and see what else I can do with it I would like to update the second ng-repeat based off the selection using the ng-click directive and see what I can make!

Comment: You could just create a new array with the index you selected: 
$scope.new_array = $scope.data.day[index];

and use this array to show the selected data.

Comment: Have any more knowledge I have it displaying in my console view but am struggling understand how exactly I am displaying it from a foreach. http://plnkr.co/edit/S84lzY7T57afbkBRlBOK

Comment: I've edited your plunker, you can see it working here: http://plnkr.co/edit/Gvw7IzzDucDOzc78pBLN?p=preview

Your ng-repeat was not repeating over your new created $scope.day array. Also, you should clear the array every time you call renderPage function. Hope I helped :)